# Problems with my Time Machine drive on my Ubuntu server

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, time-machine

Complete Linux novice here, I've been trying to set up one of my disks in my server as a Time Machine backup.

Below is a follow up from this post: http://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/1r7rzy/trouble_setting_up_time_machine_share_on_ubuntu/

I've been Google-fuing away with some success, I deleted and reinstalled NetaTalk, I could see the server but when I tried to set it up I got this error:

```
Time Machine can't access the backup disk "TimeMachine". 

The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error 2.)
```

A quick change of permissions fixed that.

I can now access my drive on my server and point Time Machine to it. Only one problem, it's only showing less than ~30GB of space on the drive.

For a quick test I tried creating a folder on the Time Machine drive on my Mac but it never showed up on the Ubuntu side.

Screenshots - https://i.stack.imgur.com/huRfh.jpg

Now this could be two things;

1. It could be pointing to my OS SSD in the sever
2. The size of the Time Machine drive is limited some how.

This is what is in the */etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default* file at the moment

```
# By default all users have access to their home directory
#~/                "Home Directory"   options:usedots,upriv    ea:ad
/mnt/TimeMachine/tm_backup "TimeMachine" options:usedots,upriv,tm ea:ad allow:myusername
```

Tried redefining where the backup is

```
mkdir /mnt/TimeMachine/tm_backup
sudo chown username:username /mnt/TimeMachine/tm_backup
chmod 755 /mnt/TimeMachine/tm_backup
```

But it's still saying that there is ~30GB of space on the drive

Second guide I used:
ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811541

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found the solution with time but just in case.
I had the same error but with a Debian 7
And I correct it just by removing a Comment I had on my shared drive.

my rights are

- chmod -R 775
- chown -R root:users

Comment: Which comment did you remove?  This answer isn't much help without that.

Comment: The comment you give to your share into the afp.conf to describe your share.

http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.1/htmldocs/afp.conf.5.html

Such as example my share was "tm_jodumont" with the comment/description of "Time Machine for JOduMonT" and my Time Machine wasn't able to write in until I remove my comment/description on my share.